# How to extract and clean data from a .csv file using Python without using Pandas?

Tags: python, csv

| Text | Number1 | Number2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| funs | 6 | 1 |
| mans | 8 | 0 |
| runs | 12 | 7 |

If I had a .csv file that had 3 columns with many rows, how would I extract just the first column and disregard the 2nd and 3rd column.

Here is my code that I have tried

```
import csv
og_data = open("original_dataset.csv","r")
  reader_variable = csv.reader(og_data, delimiter = ",")
  for row in reader_variable:
    print(row)
```

This prints out each row as a list of three elements. In the end, I am trying to extract the first column and I think it would be best if it was one big string.

Comment: Like funsmansruns?

Comment: You’ve almost answered your own question… so close :) If the CSV reader iterates the file returning a _list_ of strings, and the CSV writer (btw) also writes lists of values with its writerow(row) method, then how would you keep the first element from each row/list during the read and pass it on to the writer? Maybe try creating a CSV writer and just see what it takes to write funs, mans, and runs. If you can get that, I’m sure you’ll see what to do with the read loop. And definitely check Python’s CSV documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Csv files are simple text files that you can open with any text editor. Similarly, you can use open function in python to read the file
Like so:

```
with open('file txt', 'r') as file:
    lines = file.readlines() #returns a list of strings
```

To take only the first column you can something like this:

```
First_col = [line.split(',')[0] for line in lines]
```

And to make the first column into a single big string you can use the .join method; like this:

```
','.join(First_col)
```

Note the the method is called on the desired separator and takes the list it needs to join.